# High response time on Azure Web App

Tags: web-services, azure, azure-web-app-service, performance-testing, message-queue

I have developed a RESTful api that I deployed on Azure Web App. While performing the load test using JMeter, I see that the response time is huge i.e ~18secs. This response time appalls me because the endpoint I have exposed only receives a ~1-2KB of text data and enqueues it to azure service bus queue.

I have researched and found the following:

1. Azure Web App and Queue needs to be in the same region. **Yes they are**
2. Size of the VM matters. **Mine is S3 Large**
3. Software Design needs to be good/optimized. **Controller only enqueues, no other operations**

For load testing, I have provisioned a VM instance in the same region as the Azure Web App to minimize the latency. The enqueue statement takes time in the order of milliseconds, so I wonder what is taking the extra seconds while the serivce is in load?

**EDIT**: My code creates a single instance of `QueueClient` which I reuse for all requests. The code is just the following two lines inside an `ApiController`

```
ServiceBusManager.GetQueueWriter().Enqueue(data); //data is no more than ~1KB                
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Data enqueued");
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Since you mention queues, is "response time" the delay coming back from the REST API call, or is it the time before the queue message is processed? I've seen queue delivery delays vary wildly, from nearly-instantaneous to 30 seconds or more.

Comment: Did you look into the initialization of you service bus queue client? Are you recreating the the queue client in the controller constructor? This could add up pretty quickly, especially if ServiceBus is limiting your connection count. If so, you should look into using dependency injection to reuse the instance. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements

Comment: @McGuireV10 response time is the delay coming back from the REST API call. The queue message processing only takes ~300ms in this case.

Comment: @AlexAIT I have a singleton class that creates a single instance of QueueClient and then I reuse that instance for all the requests.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several possible reasons:

1. Your Azure VM simply gets overloaded (i.e lacks CPU or RAM) so make sure it has enough headroom to operate. You can monitor VM resources consumption using [Azure Diagnostics Extension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-virtual-machine-monitoring-with-wad-extension/) or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
2. Your JMeter machine is overloaded. Default JMeter configuration is good for tests development and/or debugging, when it comes to load testing make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html).
3. The problem could be in your application code, re-run your test with profiler tool telemetry (i.e. using [YourKit .NET Profiler](https://www.yourkit.com/.net/profiler/)) - this will allow you to detect the heaviest methods, largest objects, slowest DB queries, etc.
4. Infrastructure configuration might not be suitable for high loads. Check your application server, database and other middleware settings and make sure there are enough threads to serve virtual users generated by JMeter, otherwise requests will be queuing up.

Comment: 1- From the charts on the portal, I see that CPU and RAM are not overloaded. RAM usage is under ~200MB and CPU usage is also way too less.
2- Alternatively, I have also tested with Azure Cloud-based Load Testing tool and the results are pretty much the same - high response time.
3- I have updated my question with code, it looks pretty simple and straight forward though I'll look into the profiler.
4- The only machine involved is Azure Web App, which I have scaled up to the highest offering on Azure (Isolated Machine) and the time seems to be improved by ~8secs but still its high (~8-10secs)